# Mean instantaneous drift from option prices

Tags: options, stochastic-drift

I'm going through the paper "[Pricing European Options in Realistic Markets](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0210025)" by Schaden (2002) as its formulation for instantaneous mean drift seemed really interesting.

On page 14, the author says that it can be expressed via greeks for any European-style call:

α = - (call_vega - 0.5*call_delta + 0.5*call_gamma) / call_delta

However, from current market prices, I'm getting negative drift, and the paper seems to frequently imply that this drift is positive. That is, constant α > 0 qualitatively reproduces the volatility smile and term structure often observed in equity markets. (For α=0, everything is reduced to BSM's assumption of constant volatility.)

Furthermore, it implies that this α is constant across strikes within a particular expiration, but this is also negated by a simple test case.

Is it possible that I'm completely misinterpreting the above equation and, if so, what am I missing?

Comment: A few general notes as I haven't read the paper in detail: The formula for $\alpha$ should include theta, not vega. The instantaneous option return $\alpha$ is such that $\mathbb{E}_t[\text{d}C]=\alpha C\text{d}t$, where $\mu$ is the expected return of the underlying stock. By Itô's Lemma, $\mathbb{E}_t[\text{d}C]=\left(\Theta+\mu S\Delta+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\Gamma\right)\text{d}t$. Thus, $\alpha=\frac{\Theta+\mu S\Delta+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\Gamma}{C}$. The formula in the paper seems differ by operating in log-space etc. [1/2]

Comment: In the risk-neutral world, $\mathbb{E}_t^\mathbb{Q}[\text{d}C]=rC\text{d}t$ with $\mathbb{E}_t^\mathbb{Q}[\text{d}C]=\left(\Theta+r S\Delta+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\Gamma\right)\text{d}t$. The excess return of the option is thus $\alpha-r=\frac{S\Delta}{C}(\mu-r)$. The ratio $\frac{S\Delta}{C}=\frac{\partial C/C}{\partial S/S}$ is called elasticity and is strictly bigger than one for call options (negative for put options). Thus, the expected excess returns of calls exceeds the expected excess return of its underlying. Straight-forward to generalise the above to, eg, stochastic vol models. [2/2]

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Is theta defined here by total decay till expiration, or the one-day expected time decay?